# Как не отправлять некоторые данные пользователя в request Django

Tags: python, django

В модели пользователя есть данные, которые я бы хотел оставлять секретными и не отсылать/не использовать в request, то есть, чтобы поле модели пользователя игнорировалось и не добавлялось в request.
Каким наилучшим способом это можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте создать свою модель пользователя.